# How to convert LWFN to TTF?

Tags: macos, fonts

Looking for an easy (preferably free) way to convert a few Mac PostScript Type 1 (LWFN) fonts to TTF.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [fondu](http://fondu.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I tried that before, but I get an error during installation. All it says is "The installation failed."
Only reason I can think is because it's a somewhat older program and I'm running 10.6?

Comment: Could you try compiling it from the source?

Comment: If some people ran into that issue while using fondu : "Can't find an appropriate resource fork in _font name_", you can fix it by typing `fondu font_name/..namedfork/rsrc`

Answer (score 3):

1. Use [fondu](http://fondu.sourceforge.net/) to convert it into a .bdf file. 
   (installing fondu may return 'installation failed' but it runs anyway.)
2. a) copy your font to the desktop  b) open a terminal and type `cd

   Desktop/` c) then type `fondu YOURFONTNAME`, it will create a .bdf
   file
3. And then use a standard font converter e.g. http://www.freefontconverter.com/ to convert the .bdf to a .ttf (TrueType) or .otf (OpenType) file.